# Faster method to operate on all characters in a text file

Tags: string, bash, loops, text, text-files

I want to execute a task on a very long string for which I think I need to operate on each character individually. Before doing so I'm trying to **establish a baseline of the amount of time required to access all those characters** in the first place.

The input I intend to use is a text file with **a single line containing a single word** composed of digits.

The code below is my best attempt so far, **are there faster methods for accessing all characters in a string one by one**?

```
function handle_split() {
    split=$1
    while read -N 1 char; do
        :
    done
}

while read -N 100000 split; do
    ((i=i%100)); ((i++==0)) && wait
    handle_split $split &
done < "filename.txt"
```

This line is intended to avoid queuing more than a 100 tasks at the same time

```
((i=i%100)); ((i++==0)) && wait
```

The length of the split is hardcoded based on the known length of the input, in this case I'm using a string of about a billion characters.

---

As an aside I tried to convert my string splits into arrays looking for an increase in performance.

```
function handle_split() {
    split=($@)
    for char in ${split[@]}; do
        :
    done
}

while read -N 100 split; do
   arr=($(echo $split | grep -o .))
   ((i=i%100)); ((i++==0)) && wait
   handle_split "${arr[@]}" &
done < "filename.txt"
```

But this implementation with arrays was even slower than a simple for loop.

```
while read -N 1 char; do
    :
done < "filename.txt"
```

Comment: Shell loops will be a pure disaster in your case. They are not intended for that many iterations. If you explain a bit what processing you have in mind for each character we can probably propose something considerably more efficient using `sed`, `awk`, `python`, `perl` or something else. For instance, could it be tabulated? I mean, if your characters are digits, and you just want to translate them into another character set, `tr` is probably what you need.

Comment: I'm trying to sort an input like "15487355732.." into something like "111222333..", while I can do that with sort, I was thinking it could be done faster by creating an hashmap of the number of occurrences for each digit, the processing would be to add 1 to the value stored in the appropriate key, possibly dumping the result of each task into a separate file.

Comment: Also, I'm aware that the loop approach isn't the best, I just wanted to make sure I tried the best implementation of it, so that I could say "so, this is the best that could be done with a loop and it's not good enough, so anything using loops can be discarded".

Comment: You could organize thing in any possible way, processing each of your billions of digits with shell commands will take an incredible amount of time. Finding out which implementation is the less catastrophic is only of theoretical interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU or BSD `awk` is probably a good choice here:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=""}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}
  END {for(i=0;i<10;i++) for(j=0;j<a[i];j++) printf "%d", i}' file
```

should be about what you want. Explanation: `FS=""` in the `BEGIN` block means that each single character in the file is a separate field. The `{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}` block loops over all fields (1 to `NF`) and for each of them it increments one of the 10 cells of the `a` array. The `END` block is executed at the END and it prints each digit `d` as many times as `a[d]`, in increasing order of digits.

Note that this does not print a final newline. If you need one add `; print ""` at the end of the block:

```
END {for(i=0;i<10;i++) for(j=0;j<a[i];j++) printf "%d", i; print ""}
```

Of course, the result is so redundant that you could prefer a more compact form, like, for instance one line per character with two fields: the character and the number of occurrences:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=""}
  {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++}
  END {for(i in a) printf "%s %d\n", i, a[i]}' file
```

Just tested this last one on a 3.6 GHz Intel Core i7, with a 1.4GB input: 2m38.480s.

Comment: This requires GNU awk.

Comment: Good point, thanks, added this. Note that it also works with BSD `awk`.

Comment: I timed the awk script (without the END block) and the result is slightly faster than the multiprocessing one I wrote, while using far less system resources, so I think I can accept this as answer. Regarding the sorting bit, this is still too slow by one or two orders of magnitude.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that it is only "slightly" faster. Did you test this on very large input files? And if you can afford 100 processes why not splitting your input in as many chunks and `awk` them in parallel? Combining the results should be trivial, especially with the compact output version.

Comment: You were right, parallelizing the awk script was so fast that I can use it for the sorting problem. On my machine just the splitting and processing of each file (without merge of the results) takes less than 90 seconds on a 10^9 characters string.